# I am having uitableview not uitableview controller.And I want to load url inside uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am having uitableview not uitableview controller.And I want to load url inside uitableview but viewdidload method not working in uitableview method.How can I load url in uitableview

.m file

```
#import "HHContentTableView.h"
#import "MyCustomCell.h"

@interface HHContentTableView ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation HHContentTableView

+ (HHContentTableView *)contentTableView
{
    HHContentTableView *contentTV = [[HHContentTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    contentTV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    contentTV.dataSource = contentTV;
    contentTV.delegate = contentTV;
     [contentTV registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    return contentTV;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell.leftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@(indexPath.row)];
    cell.rightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@(indexPath.row)];
    cell.middleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@(indexPath.row)];
}
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HHContentTableView : UITableView

+ (HHContentTableView *)contentTableView;

@end
```

Refer HHHorizontalPagingView sample project to understand more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't. `UITableView` is a UI component, so it basically should not deal with loading URLs.

But if you insist, you can do it inside of any delegate method that you implement there.

You can also expose some method outside that will do it.

But the proper way would be to load the URL outside your `TableView` and pass the results to it. For example you can do in the same `ViewController` that initializes the `TableView`.

Comment: help me to pass array values using delegate method